# sabre error while trying to add baggage with ticket

Tags: soap, soap-client, sabre, sabredav

Trying to issue ticket with baggage but getting below error.
executed TravelItineraryReadRQ it has BG ALLOWANCE 5KG 737 DOMESTIC

```
<AirTicketRS Version="2.9.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
         <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-04-27T07:38:49-05:00">
               <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                  <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="193180">W¥EMD¥FCA¥BA*1P05K</stl:HostCommand>
                  <stl:Message>FORMAT-CHECK ENTRY COMMENCING WITH EMD-0197</stl:Message>
                  <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
               </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
         </stl:ApplicationResults>
      </AirTicketRS>
```

Following is request of AirTicketLLSRQ

```
 <soapenv:Body>
          <ns:AirTicketRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" NumResponses="1" Version="2.9.0">
             <!--Optional:-->
             <ns:OptionalQualifiers>
                <ns:FOP_Qualifiers>
                   <!--Optional:-->
                   <ns:BasicFOP Type="CA">                  
                   </ns:BasicFOP>               
                </ns:FOP_Qualifiers>    
                <ns:MiscQualifiers>
                        <ns:BaggageAllowance  Number="1" Weight="05" />
                        <ns:Ticket Type="EMD"  />
                </ns:MiscQualifiers>
             </ns:OptionalQualifiers>        
          </ns:AirTicketRQ>
       </soapenv:Body>
```

Please let me know what i am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is that you cannot sell EMDs that way.
The `<ns:Ticket Type="EMD"  />` is for you to sell the AirExtra after you created it. Once created you can call the AirTicket service with the air extra line number.

In order to add the air extra you can use the information in this guide:
http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/pnrservices/AE_SWS_Sell_Cancel_User_Guide_v1_12.pdf

Comment: I followed steps mention in the document. Request : <ns:AirTicketRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" NumResponses="2" Version="2.9.0">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:OptionalQualifiers>
            <ns:FOP_Qualifiers>
               <ns:BasicFOP Type="CA"></ns:BasicFOP>
            </ns:FOP_Qualifiers>
            <ns:MiscQualifiers>
               <ns:AirExtras Number="1"/>
               <ns:Ticket Type="EMD"/>
            </ns:MiscQualifiers>
         </ns:OptionalQualifiers>
      </ns:AirTicketRQ>

Comment: but getting this error.  Response :          <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-05-01T11:34:42-05:00">
               <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                  <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="03C64B">W¥EMD*AE1¥FCA</stl:HostCommand>
                  <stl:Message>FORMAT-CHECK ENTRY COMMENCING WITH E-0061</stl:Message>
                  <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
               </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
         </stl:ApplicationResults>

Comment: W¥EMD*AE1¥FCA is the command generated, according to the link below it should be correct, you should check with the help desk. https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/MiscellaneousTicketDocuments/ElectronicMiscellaneousDocumentsEMD/ElectronicMiscellaneousDocumentsEMDIssueSLVoidSLRefund.aspx?ItemID=1083f10541844beb90a0881bb781b867&tabtype=format&documentId=1083f10541844beb90a0881bb781b867_overview_format

Comment: Thanks, So can we use MISCServicesRQ instead of AirTicketLLSRQ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, MISCServices service is for airline customers only, so if you are developing for an airline, I think you can.

Comment: Hi, I'm confronted to the same issue.
I added Ancillary to the booking with an UpdateReservationRQ.
I called AirTicketRQ with :
<ns:AirExtras Number="1"/>
<ns:Ticket Type="EMD"/>
but error in AirTicketRS :
AirTicketLLS failed with Cause: AirTicketLLSRQ: FORMAT-CHECK ENTRY COMMENCING WITH EMD*AE1-0018
Do you have an idea why ?
And also, what Number should I put in <ns:AirExtras Number="1"/> ?

Thanks a lot